# How do I modify a CDATA Node in WiX with the XmlFile element?

Tags: xml, wix, cdata, wix-extension

I am trying to modify an XML configuration file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <applicationSettings>
        <App.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="FeedAddress" serializeAs="String">
                <value><![CDATA[http://feedaddress.tld]]></value>
            </setting>
        </App.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

with this [XmlFile](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd%5Cutil%5Cxmlfile.html) element:

```
<util:XmlFile
    Id="SetFeedAddress"
    Action="setValue"
    ElementPath="//configuration/applicationSettings/App.Properties.Settings/setting[\[]@name='FeedAddress'[\]]/value"
    File="[INSTALLFOLDER]App.exe.config"
    SelectionLanguage="XPath"
    Value="{[FEEDADDRESS]}"
    Sequence="4"/>
```

But the outcome is that the CDATA tag is removed and replaced by the text. I want to preserve the CDATA tag. I guess there should be several solutions for this problem.

One solution I have tried is modifying the XmlFile element to include the CDATA Tag like this:

```
Value="&lt;![CDATA[{[FEEDADDRESS]}]]&gt;"
```

But to no avail. The extension throws an error in this case.

Then I tried adding dummy properties holding the CDATA tag like this:

```
<Property Id="CDATASTART"><![CDATA[<![CDATA[]]></Property>
<Property Id="CDATAMID"><![CDATA[]]]]></Property>
<Property Id="CDATAEND"><![CDATA[>]]></Property>
```

And then I added them to the Value:

```
Value="{[CDATASTART]}{[FEEDADDRESS]}{[CDATAMID]}{[CDATAEND]}"
```

But this results in the following string:

```
&lt;![CDATA[http://host.tld]]&gt;
```

Somehow the extension replaces the *smaller than* and *greater than* signs with their XML entities.

So I guess the best solution would be if I could select the inner text element of the CDATA element with an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression and then modify that node. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The CDATA in your examples is spurious. It's not necessary when representing that text. Most XML processors are going to minimize the use of CDATA when writing XML documents. It is not an XML node; It's just a way of representing a text node.

Comment: see the following url: it throws an error, if the value is not enclosed in a CDATA Tag (at least in wix):
`http://derstandard.at/?page=rss&ressort=seite1`  
The error is:  
`Entity 'ressort' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, this is another non-answer... I get it now. Your problem isn't how to produce or retain CDATA in the XML output-the XML processor will do that when required. The problem is how to get the a property value substitution into the XML DOM that XmlFile is using so that it is emitted as a correctly encoded XML attribute value. I think the problem is in the extension. The source code might help us figure it out.